# How long do I need to rest for?

Tags: manyland

I tried to place a block and it said 'I need a rest!'. How long do I need to wait before I can continue building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your rank and how much you built, but generally, things should be back to normal after mere minutes.